# How do I just sign in a user without asking for access tokens to resources?

Tags: msal.js, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm trying to use the MSAL.js library to sign in Azure AD and Microsoft account users. Right now, I use `acquireTokenPopup()` which requires me to pass scopes for an API. I'd like to *just* sign in the user without getting access tokens.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSAL.js provides login methods to sign in users. The [loginRedirect() and loginPopup()](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki/Public-APIs#login-apis) methods take scopes as an optional parameter in case you want to request scopes ahead for user consent. But it does not require you to pass scopes or get tokens for an API.

You can read more about MSAL.js usage [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-core/README.md).